# C# Optimizing a function by pre-loading it

Tags: c#, xml, optimization

I have a function that is very small, but is called so many times that my profiler marks it as time consuming. It is the following one:

```
private static XmlElement SerializeElement(XmlDocument doc, String nodeName, String nodeValue)
{
     XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement(nodeName);
     newElement.InnerXml = nodeValue;
     return newElement;
}
```

The second line (where it enters the nodeValue) is the one takes some time.

The thing is, I don't think it can be optimized code-wise, I'm still open to suggestions on that part though.
However, I remember reading or hearing somewhere that you could tell the compiler to flag this function, so that it is loaded in memory when the program starts and it runs faster.

Is this just my imagination or such a flag exists?

Thanks,

FB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways you can cause it to be jitted early, but it's not the jit time that's hurting you here.

If you're having performance problems related to Xml serialization, you might consider using [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) rather than XmlDocument, which is fairly heavy.  Also, most automatic serialization systems (including the built-in .NET XML Serialization) will emit code dynamically to perform the serialization, which can then be cached and re-used.  Most of this has to do with avoiding the overhead of reflection, however, rather than the overhead of the actual XML writing/parsing.

Comment: Yes but I am serializing up to 4Mo of data (size of the resulting XML file), isn't XmlDocument supposed to be better in that case?

Comment: XmlDocument provides a cached model that allows for easier manipulation of the structure of the data before it is written to disk.  If you need that flexibility, XmlDocument is easier to work with.  However, if you already know the structure well in advance and don't need access to the cached, hierarchical model, XmlWriter will perform much better.  This is particularly true for large files, since it is not caching any information other than what is being buffered to the underlying stream as it writes.

Comment: Ok well, I will try that, thank you.
One a side note, nobody really answered my original question, just my imagination?

Comment: Half your imagination, half misinformation. See my edited answer.

Comment: @FatalBaboon, I'm not aware of a flag for a particular method, but you can pre-compile a native image of an entire assembly using the ngen utility.  Again, this only helps with the initial compilation of the assembly IL, but not with runtime performance once it's been jitted.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you Euphoric, I wish I could select 2 answers as accepted :(

Answer (score 3):

I dont think this can be solved using any kind of catching or inlining. And I believe its your imagination. Mainly the part about performance. What you have in mind is pre-JIT-ing your code. This technique will remove the wait time for JITer when your function is first called. But this is only first time this function is called. It has no performance effect for subsequent calls.

As [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innerxml%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) states, setting InnterXml parses set string as XML. And parsing XML string can be expensive operation, especialy if set xml in string format is complex. And documentation even has this line:

> InnerXml is not an efficient way to modify the DOM. There may be performance issues when replacing complex nodes. It is more efficient to construct nodes and use methods such as InsertBefore, InsertAfter, AppendChild, and RemoveChild to modify the Xml document.

So, if you are creating complex XML structure this way it would be wise to do it by hand.

Comment: As a corollary to this answer, if you're not actually setting inner XML content, use Value instead.

Comment: Using value instead of innerXML made me save 1% of execution time. but it does the exact same thing oO. I hope there's no mistake being made... I couldn't see one.